# Need help for Flatlist and array

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good aftrnoon,
Actually i cannot view the flatlist with my array content. Array add correctly data but flatlist don't show nothing .Plus i'd like to set a button on each row of array into flatlist.

Data "chosenDate" , is data received from a datapicker ( example : "27 Agosto 2019 16:59" ) and add into array

Thanks for help .

```
var SampleArray = [];

export default class DateTimePickerTester extends Component {
handleDatePicked = date => {

    this.setState({ chosenDate: moment(date).format('Do , MMMM YYYY HH:mm') });
    SampleArray.push(this.state.chosenDate.toString())
    console.log(SampleArray.toString());

  };
 FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
 render() {

    return (
      <>
   <FlatList
            data={this.SampleArray}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            )}></FlatList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved by this.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.array = [],
      this.state = {
        isDateTimePickerVisible: false,
        chosenDate: '',
        arrayHolder: [],
       };
  }

.....

 handleDatePicked = date => {
    this.setState({ chosenDate: moment(date).format('Do , MMMM YYYY HH:mm') },
      () => this.array.push({title : this.state.chosenDate.toString()})
    );
    this.setState({ arrayHolder: [...this.array] })

  };

.....
      <FlatList
            data={this.state.arrayHolder}
            width='100%'
            extraData={this.state.arrayHolder}

            keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key'+index}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={style.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.title)} > {item.title} </Text>}
          />
```

Any suggestions to improve something?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

//sample code

```
renderListNotes = () => {
return(
<FlatList
data={data}
renderItem={(note) =>{
if (note) {
return <NoteView key={note.noteId} note={note} event={this.props.event}/> }    
}}
/>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your setState method like this

```
this.setState({
  chosenDate: moment(date).format('Do , MMMM YYYY HH:mm') 
},
() => SampleArray.push(this.state.chosenDate.toString())
);
```

As setState is an async method so you need to handle the push function as a callback of setState.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add data to an array, `Flatlist` does not render itself again, so you need to re-render it using the `Onfresh` function. Click the `Flatlist` list and scroll down. Then your data will be updated with the **indicator**.

```js
handleDatePicked(date){

    this.setState({ chosenDate: moment(date).format('Do , MMMM YYYY HH:mm') }, () => SampleArray.push(this.state.chosenDate.toString()) );
    console.log(SampleArray.toString());

  };
...
 <FlatList
           refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
           onRefresh={this.handleDatePicked}
```

**Example**

```js
var SampleArray = ['2017','2018'];

class ScreenComponentOne extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      refreshing: false,
      date: 'gg',
    }
  }
   static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: `First`,
    };
  };

  testfunc() {
  }

   onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ date: '2019'}, () => SampleArray.push(this.state.date));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}>
         <FlatList
           refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
           onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
            data={SampleArray}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <TouchableHighlight style={{width:"100%",height:40,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            )}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```